# Javascript Facebook SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using JavaScript Facebook SDK for sharing my post on Facebook. I am trying to share a link "http://www.google.com" through my post. For that I am using "properties" field that Facebook JavaScript SDK provides.

Whenever I try to post something, Facebook displays the link in a preview, however the same link is not visible when the post is shared on Facebook wall.

Below is the code which I am using

```
var p = {
  "Look at details": {
    "text": "here",
    "href": "http://www.google.com"
  }
};

FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  name: 'Los Angeles, CA, United States',
             caption: 'The current condition for Los Angeles is Fair.',
             description: 'Temperature is 58&deg;F.\nLook at details: <a href="www.google.com">here</a>',
             link: 'www.google.com',
             properties: p
}, function(response){});
```

Before posting to facebook wall..

[image]

After posting to facebook wall....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely html  tags aren't allowed in the description field. But it's worth a try to escape the double quotes (\"). Have you looked at the html of that link using firebug/dev tools inspector?

Comment: But i am having problem with "properties" field.